# How to get Rackspace Cloud object header

Tags: java, rackspace-cloud, rackspace-cloudfiles

I am trying to `update` header data of some `Rackspace` objects i have uploaded. Example header `attribute` like: `X-Object-Meta-name`

But to do that, currently i need to download the whole `object` and `parse` the `header` from the downloaded object. Then do some checking and update if necessary and then upload the object again. But this makes the updating process very slow.

Is there a way to only download the `header` part of an `object` and updating it alone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-swift/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/swift/v1/features/ObjectApi.java#L207

If you give it a map with "name"->"the updated header value", it should update the header and automatically add the x-object-meta- prefix.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only download the header part of an object and updating it alone?

I am not a Java developer, but the Cloud Files API is a RESTful one, so I will provide examples using curl.  If you are using a library then you may want to edit your question to include which library as many of them abstract these opperations and a better answer can probably be provided in the context of that library.

To download the headers without the object content, perform a HTTP HEAD request.

```
$ curl -I -XHEAD -H'X-Auth-Token:******' \
> https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_******/container/object
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:06:23 GMT
Etag: 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
X-Timestamp: 1429617982.70468
X-Object-Meta-Foo: Bar
Content-Type: text/html
X-Trans-Id: txd337e4634c98475baf1a4-0055363d42dfw1
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:06:26 GMT
```

To update just the headers on the object, you can then perform a HTTP POST request.

```
$ curl -i -XPOST -H'X-Auth-Token:******' \
> -H'X-Object-Meta-Foo: Bar' \
> -H'X-Object-Meta-Foo2: Bar2' \
> https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_******/container/object
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Trans-Id: txc262dfe86727440cbfcb1-0055363d5cdfw1
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:06:53 GMT

<html><h1>Accepted</h1><p>The request is accepted for processing.</p></html>
```

Performing another HEAD requeset will show that both the headers are now present.

```
$ curl -I -XHEAD -H'X-Auth-Token:******' \
> https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_******/container/object
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:06:53 GMT
Etag: 81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055
X-Timestamp: 1429618012.98354
X-Object-Meta-Foo: Bar
X-Object-Meta-Foo2: Bar2
Content-Type: text/html
X-Trans-Id: txdd9365b54e8f4d8c8451d-0055363d6adfw1
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 12:07:06 GMT
```